# MKMapView default region or copy/duplicate initial state?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mkmapview, core-location

After creating a Map View in the storyboard, the default location on the simulator shows up as the United States. Looking from [other SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102292/mkmapview-zoom-to-default-country-level), there seems not to be a way to replicate this image since we are not given the [default span or region](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850475/3751589) (or any way to access the user's current country and get the corresponding region and span data).

The default map view for the US looks like this:
[image]

Is there a way to copy or duplicate the initial state of the map view, so that we can restore it later?

I currently have a "reset" button, but I'm not sure what to reset to. Perhaps make the default region/span the user's current location, if there are no better solutions?